# how to make directory on the google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

how to make directory on the google colab?
I can not make the new directory on google driver on google colab?

Comment: Either using `!mkdir [folder]` or use `from os import mkdir; mkdir('[folder]')`

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking for creating new folder in the 'Files' section (to the left from notebook) - you can run in **code shell**:

```
!mkdir new_folder
```

Just remember, that Colab is a temporary environment with an idle timeout of 90 minutes and an absolute timeout of 12 hours.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `!mkdir foldername` command to create folder in the current working directory. It will be by default /content.

If you want to create directory with specific condition then use `os.mkdir('folder_path')` to create the directory.

```
import os.path
from os import path

if path.exists('/content/malayalam_keyphrase_extraction') == False:
  os.mkdir('/content/malayalam_keyphrase_extraction')

os.chdir('/content/malayalam_keyphrase_extraction')
!pwd
!ls
```

or

```
!mkdir malayalam_keyphrase_extraction
```

**NB: malayalam_keyphrase_extraction is the folder name**

Answer (score 2):

The way you want to do this is as follows:

1. Mount your drive (i.e. Connect your Colab to your Google Drive):

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

2. Use the `os` library. It has most of your typical bash commands which you can run right from your python script:

```
import os

path = "gdrive/MyDrive/Rest/Of/Path"
os.mkdir(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this, then see the result

[image]

You can use feature upload file(s) in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

> mkdir "/content/drive/My Drive/name"

Comment: Could you give more information on how to use the commands you gave ?

Comment: !mkdir make a new folder and after that is the path and folder name

!mkdir "/content/drive/My Drive/abc"